# How to ensure documentation shows alternate #ifdef'd code

Tags: documentation, typedef, doxygen, conditional-compilation

I'm developing a cross-platform library. Some pieces of code are platform dependent, so I have to separate them using `#ifdef`, checking the platform type. I split one class into two classes, each for their own platform. These classes have different names, but finally I need to `typedef` these classes to one type according to the platform:

```
#ifdef UNIX
/** some comment */
typedef Key_unix Key;
#elif WIN
/** another comment */
typedef Key_win Key;
#endif
```

The generated documentation is showing only the first `typedef` with both comments. How can I show both `typedef`s together, each with its own comment?

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand, doxygen has its own preprocessor that will evaluate #ifdefs. You can define macros using the `PREDEFINED` option.

```
# The PREDEFINED tag can be used to specify one or more macro names that 
# are defined before the preprocessor is started (similar to the -D option of 
# gcc). The argument of the tag is a list of macros of the form: name 
# or name=definition (no spaces). If the definition and the = are 
# omitted =1 is assumed. To prevent a macro definition from being 
# undefined via #undef or recursively expanded use the := operator 
# instead of the = operator.
```

However, since you've got an #elif even if you set `PREDEFINED = UNIX WIN` it'll only evaluate the first #ifdef. As an alternative you could always try:

```
#ifdef UNIX
/** some comment */
typedef Key_unix Key;
#endif
#ifdef WIN
/** another comment */
typedef Key_win Key;
#endif
```

It's unlikely that you'll have both UNIX and WIN defined when you compile the code.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried your alternative code with and without PREDEFINED option but unfortunately it hasn't worked. I think that the problem isn't with macros but with duplicate code - typedef of the same type. Doxygen reach both because both comments are used. My qestion is in fact about if there is some Doxygen option to allow duplicate code in doc.

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean. I don't know of a way to get doxygen to document duplicate typedefs in the way you are asking.